# How to define {\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures} in .cls file

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

I am trying to use `{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` to remove spaces between figure captions of two different chapters in the list of figures.

`{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` works fine when defined in the main .tex file. But fails to work when put into the .cls file. I am getting a compilation error.

How do I define this in the .cls file.

TLDR;
`{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` does not work in the permeable. What is the correct syntax to define the above in the permeable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange. If you are writing a new class, just not adding the space in your definition of `\chapter` should be enough. But maybe I do not understand your question. Can you show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) of your problem?

Comment: @cabohah to simply put my question, I want to put `{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` into the class i am writing. But when I put `{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` in to the class file i am getting an compilation error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}` does not work in the permeable. What is the correct syntax to define the above in the permeable - @cabohah

Comment: @charcoalblock please follow the instructions of cabohah for a MWE. We can't know where you added this "part of command" or why it is enclosed in `{}` if it is not a part of command.

Comment: May be you want something like this in the preamble: `\let\originallistoffigures\listoffigures` and below `\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}\originallistoffigures}`. Or something like this. Give us a MWE so we can test and answer. Thanks

Comment: @koleygr your solution works. This was the one I was looking for. Thanks. The solution below also works. But yours is more short.

Comment: addvspace is only used in the list of figures if you use it in the commands defined in your class, so it is better simply not to use it rather than use it then redefine such a core latex command to do nothing

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Please check @DavidCarlisle comments below and just don't do it**

**Comment into answer:**

Add in your preamble or in the cls file these lines :

```
\let\originallistoffigures\listoffigures 
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{{\def\addvspace##1{}\originallistoffigures}}
```

Good luck! Happy that worked for you! and Happy TeXing!

Comment: this will redefine addvspace for the whole document after the list of figures and almost certainly break latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... Thanks. Let me TeX in there! :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you were right. The previous implementation redefined addvspace in the list of tables also(which was after the list of figures in my document). The current edited solution seems to resolve that.

Comment: @charcoalblock yes sure the group makes it slightly safer but why add `\addvspace` in your class if you do not want it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am a using the report class/package and adding modifications on top of it to suit my needs as I am very new to writing custom classes also LaTeX. Mostly I am using trial and error. Searching for a solution to my problem led me to solutions using `\addvspace`. That is how I ended up with that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle since you mentioned that the use of group is safer, does it mean ```\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
    \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
        \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
    {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
    \begingroup
        \renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}
        \@starttoc{lof}
    \endgroup
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}``` this is the most desired solution?

Comment: really the answer to the question as posted must be "don't do that" if you start redefinig such fundmental commands as `\addvspace` then things will break and your class will not be supportable.

Comment: no, any solution that involves redefining `\addvspace` is not usable in any public class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Noted, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You should not redefine `\addvspace`

The list of figures code is not defined by latex, it is defined by the class, ie *your* file. If you do not want space between captions in different chapters, simply do not add the space, don't add the space command then risk breaking latex by redefining its core commands to do nothing,

For example if your class has

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    %%%%%%%\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    %%%%%%%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

chapters in your class would be like those in report class, but not add space to lot and lof files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to getting rid of the effect of this in `.lof` file:

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces first figure}}{3}{}%
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2.1}{\ignorespaces second figure}}{5}{}%
```

I used this input:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{One}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  some graphics
  \caption{first figure}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  some graphics
  \caption{second figure}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The simplest way to obtain what you desire is

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
```

However `\addvspace` is used by many LaTeX constructs so it has to be tested in your real life case.  Naturally, the scope of the change is limited via `\begingroup/\endgroup`.

Output:
[image: output of list of figures]

Comment: edit: I realize now you are authoring a `.cls` file.  So `\renewcomamnd\listoffigures{\if@twocolumn \@restonecoltrue \onecolumn \else \@restonecolfalse \fi \chapter *{\listfigurename }\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \listfigurename }{\MakeUppercase \listfigurename }\begingroup\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}\@starttoc {lof}\endgroup\if@restonecol \twocolumn \fi }` would work assuming your class is based on book class.

Comment: Now I understand how to get the desired effect by defining it in the class file. This is the \listoffigures implementation for the book package edited with \renewcommand\addvspace[1]{} added. Thanks this works as desired. **PS: I was aware of using `\begingroup \renewcommand\addvspace[1]{} \listoffigures \endgroup` but i was expecting for a way to define this in the class file.** Also the solution by @koleygr in the comment above also works. It is also short.

Comment: @charcoalblock there is no possible reason to redefine \addvspace. You are writing the class, just add space where you need space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will take that into account. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @charcoalblock comment of @DavidCarlisle is better advised than my answer.  You are writing the class so avoid including in `\chapter` code the part which adds the `\addvspace` to start with.  That should have been my answer, but as I only roughly read your post I was not fully aware you are a class author here, so in control of most everything.